# firebase-query in dom-repeat to populate a grid

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, polymer, polymerfire

I am trying to loop through an array of keys that I would like firebase-query to fetch the nodes that meet the `equal-to` condition for those keys. When it comes to Polymer, HTMl, and JavaScript, I can't figure it out.

Any help will be appreciated, below is what I have. Thanks.

```
   <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[results]]">
    <firebase-query
      id="imgQ"
      app-name="ProjectName"
      path="/images"
      order-by-child="childKeyToOrderBy"
      equal-to=[[item.key]]    
      data="{{images}}">
    </firebase-query>
    </template>


    <div id="listContainer">      
    <template items=[[images]] is="dom-repeat">    
      <div class="item">
        <iron-image class="imgGrd" sizing="cover" src="[[item.image]]"></iron-image>
      </div>    
    </template>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your dom-repeat is missing the as="image" and the src of your iron-image should include it as well

```
<div id="listContainer">      
 <template is="dom-repeat" items=[[images]] as="image">    
  <div class="item">
    <iron-image class="imgGrd" sizing="cover" src="[[image.image]]"></iron-image>
  </div>    
 </template>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for commenting but I don't think that is the problem, I have tried it before with no luck, it seems putting firebase-query in dome repeat doesn't do the job.